# Progress bar incorrect sum value

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I have a simple code for the progress bar

```
 Dim delimiter As Decimal = 0.0
    If ListOfUsers.Any() Then
        delimiter = 100.0 / ListOfUsers.Count
    End If
For Each link As String In ListOfUsers
                counter += 1
                Dim pValue As Decimal = ProgressBar1.Value
                pValue = pValue + delimiter
                ProgressBar1.BeginInvoke(Sub() ProgressBar1.Value = pValue)
Next
 End If
```

For some reason it sums incorecctly. Let's say we have `ListOfUsers.Count = 3` The delimeter will get value `100 / 3 = 33.33` which is correct. Now when it sums it gets `66.33` instead of `66.66`.

I tried using Double but the result is the same. It's probably very simple, what I'm missing here?

Comment: You can't call `Dim pValue As Decimal = ProgressBar1.Value` unless you call it via an `.Invoke` (assuming that this code is running in a background thread).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Progress Bar value is an integer, you set the value to 33.33 for example but when you read the value back out of the progress bar it is returning 33, so by summing 33 with 33.33 you are then getting 66.33.

looking at the Progress Bar class the Value property is an int
Public Property Value As Integer

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the "Dim pValue As Decimal = ProgressBar1.Value" outside the foreach loop.

Right before the loop.